# Implementation of customviewadpter

Tags: android

I have made listview with images and some text.I am trying to open a new activity on each item being clicked.However same activity is opening always regardless of which item has been clicked.Here is the code

MainActivity.java

```
public class Dslr extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{
    public static final String[] titles=new String[]{"Nikon D3300","Canon EOS 1200D","C","D"};
    public static final String[] Descriptions=new String[]{"The Nikon D3300 is the latest entry-level model to Nikon's series: an affordable and well-balanced choice to introduce you to the world of DSLR.","The Canon EOS 1200D might be a safe replacement of the nearly four-year-old 1100D model, but it holds enough weight to keep the entry-level DSLR market bubbling along.","nnvnv","ggs"};
    public static final Integer[] images={ R.drawable.d1,R.drawable.d2,R.drawable.s11,R.drawable.s2};

ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;
Button back;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dslr);
back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent s=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),M.class);
        startActivity(s);
        }
});

rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], Descriptions[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);
    }
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter=new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
    {   switch(position)
        {
    case 0: Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),D.class);
            startActivity(i);
    case 1:Intent b=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),D_1.class);
            startActivity(b);
    case 2: Intent z=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),D.class);
    startActivity(z);
        }

}
    }

    D.java

public class D extends Activity {

Button buy,back;
ImageView iv;
TextView t1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_d);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        t1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        buy=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=L&ai=CoF1Zol9ZVtzADciuoAP57pvIDfDzl6cL0MSdhLsCuI6-3rwDCAQQAigFYOXC5IOkDsgBB6oEJE_QiSIJrNnjAN5b8R-9M8Ju79TsseUlGme7UcNxXdnFBBkwlMAFBaAGJoAH2KTjTpAHA6gHpr4b2AcB4BL88bWn1rDTp6YB&sig=AOD64_3x0dFtyFndnyF_-tFHuIrwp4DQtQ&ctype=5&clui=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwi1xoHc07LJAhXRH44KHZv3BL0Qww8IJQ&adurl=http://5231.xg4ken.com/trk/v1%3Fprof%3D435%26camp%3D92%26affcode%3Dpg19701%26kct%3Dgoogle%26kchid%3D6215386675%26cid%3D84519575488%26networkType%3Dsearch%26kdv%3Dc%26kpid%3DB00KBI7ANQ%26kmc%3D105201768%26criteriaid%3Dkwd-119383492408%26adgroupid%3D22913451688%26campaignid%3D336119728%26locphy%3D9061721%26adpos%3D1o2%26url%3Dhttp://www.amazon.in/Nikon-D3200-24-2MP-Digital-18-55mm/dp/B00KBI7ANQ%3Ftag%3Dgooginhydr18418%26tag%3Dgooginkenshoo-21%26ascsubtag%3D_kenshoo_clickid_"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent b=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dslr.class);
                startActivity(b);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.d, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

D_1.java

public class D_1 extends Activity {
ImageView d;
TextView t2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_d_1);
        d=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_d_1);
        d.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_d_1);
        t2.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.d_1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your` CustomListViewAdapter` ?

Comment: Add `break;` below every `case` in `switch` statement.

Comment: Works like a charm.Man i don't know how i made such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just because your `switch case` statement keeps executing, as there is no `break` statement is written:

```
switch (position) { 
    case 0: Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),D.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    case 1: Intent b=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),D_1.class);
            startActivity(b);
            break;
    case 2: Intent z=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),D.class);
            startActivity(z);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Pleasure is all mine... @Cr7